# C#: How do you go upon constructing a multi-lined string during design time?

Tags: c#

How would I accomplish displaying a line as the one below in a console window by writing it into a variable during design time then just calling Console.WriteLine(sDescription) to display it?

```
        Options:
            -t          Description of -t argument.
            -b          Description of -b argument.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question right, what you need is the @ sign in front of your string. This will make the compiler take in your string literally (including newlines etc)

In your case I would write the following:

```
String sDescription =
@"Options:
    -t          Description of -t argument.";
```

So far for your question (I hope), but I would suggest to just use several WriteLines.
The performance loss is next to nothing and it just is more adaptable.
You could work with a format string so you would go for this:

```
string formatString = "{0:10} {1}";
Console.WriteLine("Options:");
Console.WriteLine(formatString, "-t", "Description of -t argument.");
Console.WriteLine(formatString, "-b", "Description of -b argument.");
```

the formatstring makes sure your lines are formatted nicely without putting spaces manually and makes sure that if you ever want to make the format different you just need to do it in one place.

Comment: Also, if it's as generic as in your example (which it probably isn't, but hey..) you could go for the last approach combined with some reflection. Make your /? a piece of art ;)

Comment: Even more also: if you're doing some console app and want to do it for real check out http://www.ohloh.net/projects/3874. It really makes making a user friendly/maintainable console app a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.Write("Options:\n\tSomething\t\tElse");
```

produces

```
Options:
    Something       Else
```

\n for next line, \t for tab, for more professional layouts try the field-width setting with format specifiers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If this is a `/?` screen, I tend to throw the text into a .txt file that I embed via a resx file. Then I just edit the txt file. This then gets exposed as a string property on the generated resx class.

If needed, I embed standard `string.Format` symbols into my txt for replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd normally just write three Console.WriteLine calls. I know that gives extra fluff, but it lines the text up appropriately *and* it guarantees that it'll use the right line terminator for whatever platform I'm running on. An alternative would be to use a verbatim string literal, but that will "fix" the line terminator at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

I know C# is mostly used on windows machines, but please, please, please try to write your code as platform neutral. Not all platforms have the same end of line character. To properly retrieve the end of line character for the currently executing platform you should use:

```
System.Environment.NewLine
```

Maybe I'm just anal because I am a former java programmer who ran apps on many platforms, but you never know what the platform of the future is.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" answer depends on where the information you're displaying comes from.

If you want to hard code it, using an "@" string is very effective, though you'll find that getting it to display right plays merry hell with your code formatting.

For a more substantial piece of text (more than a couple of lines), embedding a text resources is good.

But, if you need to construct the string on the fly, say by looping over the commandline parameters supported by your application, then you should investigate both StringBuilder and Format Strings.

[StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) has methods like [AppendFormat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) that accept format strings, making it easy to build up lines of format.

[Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) make it easy to combine multiple items together. Note that Format strings may be used to format things to a specific width.

To quote the MSDN page linked above:

> **Format Item Syntax**
>
> Each format item takes the following
>   form and consists of the following
>   components:
>
> {index[,alignment][:formatString]}
>
> The matching braces ("{" and "}") are
>   required.
>
> *Index Component*
>
> The mandatory index component, also
>   called a parameter specifier, is a
>   number starting from 0 that identifies
>   a corresponding item in the list of
>   objects ...
>
> *Alignment Component*
>
> The optional alignment component is a
>   signed integer indicating the
>   preferred formatted field width. If
>   the value of alignment is less than
>   the length of the formatted string,
>   alignment is ignored and the length of
>   the formatted string is used as the
>   field width.  The formatted data in
>   the field is right-aligned if
>   alignment is positive and left-aligned
>   if alignment is negative. If padding
>   is necessary, white space is used. The
>   comma is required if alignment is
>   specified.
>
> *Format String Component*
>
> The optional formatString component is
>   a format string that is appropriate
>   for the type of object being formatted
>   ...